# Flutter Web: Reading and writing query string values

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Is it possible to read/write to the query string directly, as opposed to pushing named routes to the root Navigator?

We're developing a Desktop style app, that uses an inner content area. **We would like to support deep-linking on Web, but do not rely on our root navigator to change pages so the normal approach doesn't fit.** (We use an IndexedStack + 'TabMenu' instead)

All we really need is few simple API's:

```
Window.setRoute("/foo/bar")
String route = Window.getRoute()
Window.onRouteChanged = _handleRouteChanged;
```

From there we could easily handle everything in code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35261#issuecomment-507610298 
you can get the `query parameters` by accessing `window.location.href` with the `dart:js` package:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
...
var uri = Uri.tryParse(js.context['location']['href']);
if (uri != null) return uri.queryParameters;
```

And directly change `window.location.href`

Comment: Thanks!, that's a start! Now just need a way to write to them, and bind to changes.

Comment: you can directly change window.location.href

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Flutter seems to be fighting me though, every time I change it, it changes it back.